# Check reachability of servers in java programmatically

Tags: java, database, database-connection

In my application architecture I am having two database servers primary db and secondary db server (Replica server).

In my java code I am making a connection with DB to fetch some data now what I want is I will give the IP addresses of both DB servers in my code and will check which DB server is reachable and will connect with that only. But I am not getting how to implement it, the one way is try to telnet but not a good option because I want to disable the telnet on application server for some reasons.

Is there any other and best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would just attempt the connection (using standard database classes) and handle the exceptions if the connection fails.

Even if you confirm connectivity initially, nothing prevents a network problem occurring between that test and your actual attempt to use the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can try pinging both hosts and use the one which responds. Here is a sample program.

```
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("172.16.2.0");

        // Try to reach the specified address within the timeout
        // periode. If during this periode the address cannot be
        // reach then the method returns false.
        boolean reachable = address.isReachable(10000);

        System.out.println("Is host reachable? " + reachable);
```

For a more elaborate program, see this [Ping program example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/Ping.java) in Java.

Comment: i need for a particular port number because it may possible that the server is reachable but DB is not running on the specified port.

Comment: @pyus13 You cannot ping a specific port using `isReachable`.  You need to test a connection to a socket in order to do that.  Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14906123/1247781).